# Delete system app using zip file

Tags: zip, root-access

I have rooted my **Huawei P8-Lite ALE-L21** with `superuser.zip`. After successful root I tried to change superuser app. So, I have installed *KingoUser.apk* and after that I have clicked on `superSu app -> settings -> switch superuser app`. It didn't work. So, I installed *Link2SD* app and converted KingoUser as a system app. Now, when I launching SuperSu or KingoUser, some warning message pops up and says that the su binary needs to be updated.

There is no way to flash my phone cause Huawei haven't released my build version as a stand-alone flash file.

How can I unroot my phone now ?

Comment: This topic will explane error and will solve the problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133194/remove-su-binary

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1 Unrooting Your Device**

You can unroot your phone from SuperSu itselef

*Go to SuperSu > Setting > Fullunroot.*

**Part 2: Replacing KingUser**

You can download the ready to use script for replacing it with SuperSu [Here](http://zidroid.com/how-to-get-ride-and-replace-kinguser-with-supersu-app/)

1. Download Zip file from site
2. Extract it in External Sdcard
3. Launch Terminal Emulator
4. Type `su` and give the superuser acess
5. Type `sh /sdcard/mrw/root.sh`
6. Script will automatically delete all Kinguser files amd will make SuperSu as system app
7. Update SuperSu binary

Comment: The default mount tool that comes with stock Android has its usage as `Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory`.

Comment: When you mount a partition from fresh, you do `mount DEVICE_IDENTIFIER MOUNTPOINT`. E.g., `mount /dev/mmcblkp3 /system`. When it comes to remount, you pass the option remount. If you want to remount at same location, you need not to pass device identifier, so it can be `mount -o remount /system` instead of `mount -o remount /dev/mmcblkp3 /system`. In order to mount in read-only or read-write mode, you pass `ro` or `rw` as argument. There are exceptions with mount tool in certain devices where you must mention device identifier during remount.

Comment: It's not working at all, and when I'm trying to use `su` with adb, this error goes up: `error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.`

Comment: Try su command from Terminal Emulator and see whether you are getting superuser access..If not than you can unroot as mentioned in answer..and can root again

Comment: i have tried that, same error.

Comment: look I've modified my own supersu.zip which have su binary in `data/local` directory, and it works fine with adb, now I have problem with removing old su binaries, please have a look here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133194/remove-su-binary

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question matches its title. However, this answer is for people who might arrive here in search for an answer to the question asked in the title...

how to **delete system app using zip file**.

First, see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156337) where I explain how to create a ZIP file for flashing `.apk` files. Follow that explanation but use an `updater-script` like this:

```
mount("MTD", "system", "/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system", "/system");
delete_recursive("/system/app/SomeApp");
unmount("/system");
```

Where `SomeApp` is the directory containing the `.apk` for the app that you want to delete (use an `adb shell` to acertain this path).

One could, however, just use `adb shell` to do it (but this doesn't answer the question asked):

```
$ adb shell
shell:/ $ su
root:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system
root:/ # rm -r /system/app/SomeApp
rppt:/ # reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! If you rashly attempt to install SuperSU after rooting with KingoRoot, your device would be bricked even if you uninstalled KingoRoot. KingoRoot will NOT completely remove itself when you uninstall it. The ONLY way to remove KingoRoot completely is to flash the stock ROM.

So, no, don't.