# Error: "Operation not permitted", when attempting to remove su binary placed by KingoRoot

Tags: command-line, unrooting, kingo

I rooted my P8-Lite ALE-L21 (Android 5.0.1) with supersu.zip through TWRP recovery. After that I installed KingoRoot and KingoRoot replaced  *su* binary with some other *su* binary which is obsolete for my Android version and not working. So I modified supersu.zip and placed *su* binary into another directory in `/data/local`. Now my working *su* binary is in `/data/local` and it works fine with adb, but does not work with SuperSU and other applications which use root privilege.

To solve that issue, I tried to remove these old *su* binaries:`/system/bin/su` and `/system/xbin/su`, with the following commands unsuccessfully:

```
$ adb shell
shell@hwALE-H:/ $ /data/local/su
root@hwALE-H:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system
root@hwALE-H:/ # rm /system/xbin/su
rm: /system/xbin/su: Operation not permitted
1|root@hwALE-H:/ # rm -rf /system/xbin/su
rm: /system/xbin/su: Operation not permitted
```

- What is this error: *Operation not permitted*?
- How can I remove those su files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given [this link](http://omidgfx.com/mount.txt) about `mount`'s output, it is at least confirmed that system partition is mounted in read-write mode, so we can exclude that from the list of possibilities that may be restricting `rm` from deletion. Plus, the error would be different too.

Since you're running the command with superuser privilege, different file owner or group owner of that `su` file shouldn't the cause here. It most likely would have something to do with file attributes.

To check file attributes we need `lsattr` tool. Android doesn't come with that tool, so you're left with no choice but to install busybox or toybox. Since your standard root is botched, you cannot install busybox binary using an app. It would fail. In that case, download the binary of [busybox](https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/) or [toybox](http://landley.net/toybox/bin/) appropriate for your device, rename the binary to busybox or toybox, push it into `/data/local/tmp/` and set executable permission on that file. Permission can be set using `chmod`. Do:

```
adb shell /data/local/su -c chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/<FILE>  # replace <FILE> with toybox or busybox
```

Test the binary using

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/<FILE>   # replace <FILE> with toybox or busybox
```

If it works then execute

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/<FILE> lsattr /system/xbin/su
```

Per the [output in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26555713#26555713), the file attributes are

```
-----a-A----- /system/xbin/su
```

According to [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) of `chattr`,

> When a file with the 'A' attribute set is accessed, its atime record is not modified. This avoids a certain amount of disk I/O for laptop systems.
>
> A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be open in append mode for writing. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

atime → last access time.

A file with 'a' attribute cannot be rename, delete, or overwritten, but can only be append. So that's the reason `rm` was throwing the error `operation not permitted`. (I'm surprised KingoRoot didn't place `i` attribute.)

Anyhow, we must remove that attribute first. Do:

```
adb shell /data/local/su -c /data/local/tmp/<FILE> chattr -a /system/xbin/su
```

It may not give any output unless an error occurs. Now, check the file attributes again using `lsattr`:

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/<FILE> lsattr /system/xbin/su
```

It [should now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26555856#26555856) be

```
-------A----- /system/xbin/su
```

That attribute has been removed and you're free to rename, delete and overwrite that file. To remove the file, simply do

```
adb shell /data/local/su -c rm -f /system/xbin/su
```

Follow the process for any other file, if it cannot be deleted by `rm` at once. If `lsattr` reports `i` as well, then remove it using `-i` in `chattr`.

Comment: Works like charm, Really thanks for helping me

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: hi, I need to contact you, this is urgent @firelord

Comment: @OMiD I apologize as I cannot offer my immediate assistance to you. Please feel free to post a new question or bring the issue in [chat].