# Real root can not change any thing on /system original files!

Tags: root-access, mount, system, terminal, file-permissions

On my rooted device running Android 4.2.2, I have following tools installed:

1. Terminal Emulator
2. BusyBox Free

On Terminal Emulator, `su` command successfully changes user to a real root:

```
root@hwH30-U10:/ # id -u
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
```

Then I `remount` `/system` as `R/W`:

```
root@hwH30-U10:/ # mount | grep system
/emmc@android /system ext4 rw,realtime,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Then I even:

```
root@hwH30-U10:/ # chmod 777 /system
```

But I can not change any thing e.g. permissions or contents of `/system` original files like `/system/build.prop`!

I am sure that permissions and mounts are OK because I can create a new file, `/system/tmp.prop`, change it's contents and permissions by Terminal Emulator.

I really have no idea why these operations are not permitted while in Linux point of view, all things are OK for root to do these changes!

Is there any hard-coded further protection inside Android e.g. in kernel?

How to figure out this, please?

Comment: What is the result of executing `chmod`? Have you tried any sorry of root explorer app like ES File Explorer in root mode to change the file permissions? What is your root management app and Android version?

Comment: I use SuperSU, 3C Toolbox and BusyBox on Marshmallow and KitKat without any issue.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury, `chmod` says `Operation not permitted`. and Yes, ES File Explorer in root mode, FileExpert and many other apps are unable to change any thing! My root management app is `KingRoot` on Android 4.2.2 (as I mentioned, `id -u` on `Terminal Emulator` says me that I'm realy root with id 0).

Comment: Could it be there are some SELinux enforcements in place? Not sure if the `ls` in place on the device supports it, but you could try it with either of the `-Z`/`--context`/`--lcontext`/`--scontext` parameters to have any potential SELinux context shown.

Comment: @Izzy, `ls -Z` say nothing about any context, however, Google says SELinux has been equipped into Android from version 4.3. mine is 4.2.2.

Comment: From the root terminal can you perform these steps: `cp /system/build.prop /system/build.prop.orig`; `echo lolcat > /system/build.prop`; `cat /system/build.prop`; `mv /system/build.prop.orig /system/build.prop`. I'm interested in the output of cat command.

Comment: @Firelord, `echo lolcat > /system/build.prop` fails with `k_shell/10210:17681: can't create /system/build.prop: Permission denied` as I guessed. `echo lolcat > /system/build.prop.orig` works! and `mv /system/build.prop.orig /system/build.prop` fails with `failed on ' /system/build.prop.orig': Operation not permitted` as I guessed. So, output of `cat` command is not interesting; It's the original contents.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give the result of `lsattr /system/build.prop`?

Comment: @Firelord, the result of `lsattr /system/build.prop` is `-----i--A----`, five dashes then i then two dashes then A and then four dashes.

Comment: There is the problem. It is set to immutable attribute which means the file  can't be deleted or modified. Change it like this : `chattr -i /system/build.prop` and then try that lsattr command. If the output differs this time, try my lolcat commands and tell the result.

Comment: @Firelord, excellent! I was aware about it's `i` attribute but in Linux `vi`, the command `:w!` can write even with this attribute, but it seems that BusyBox's `vi` can not! anyway, thanks a lot! If you would like, add an answer and I'll mark it as answer; Or I'll answer my question. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's actually odd if vi can edit a file having immutable attribute. Are you certain the attribute was set when you tested vi on that file? I can't save modification in the  file, even with vi, so immutable attribute works as expected in my system.

Comment: @Firelord, Previously I got messages like `(add ! to override)` and `:w!` could write. But now I created a file then `chattr +i` and you're right, `vi` can not bypass `i` attribute! Unfortunately I could not remember previous files `lsattr` but I'm sure that `:w!` could solve some messages like `(add ! to override)`. But I cannot re-produce it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [my comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134519/real-root-can-not-change-any-thing-on-system-original-files?noredirect=1#comment169664_134519) and [Yasser's subsequent comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134519/real-root-can-not-change-any-thing-on-system-original-files?noredirect=1#comment169666_134519) , I can conclude that the issue was the immutable attribute set on the file build.prop. If other files and directories also can't be edited or deleted, then they may also be having the same attribute or append-only attribute.

The remedy is to use this command with root privilege:

```
chattr -i FILE_PATH    # FILE_PATH is the file which currently has immutable attribute
```

Use `-iR` followed by a directory's path to remove immutable attribute from a directory recursively.

It is to be noted that OP already has busybox installed. `chattr` and `lsattr` aren't the utilities found natively in Android.

Relevant info about the used chattr command and append-only attribute can be found in my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133206/96277).

Comment: A note to readers: a file with immutable attribute depicts that it can't be edited, deleted, moved or renamed. You can read about Linux compatible file attributes here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr