# Can I make a flashable ZIP containing one or more APKs

Tags: apk, zip

Is it possible to make a ZIP that can be flashed onto a device to add a bundle of applications (`.apk` files) to the `/system/app` directory such that it can be flashed after the OS (e.g. CyanogenMod) in a similar way to other bundles such as OpenGApps ?

I've seen things like the ZipMe app but I'd really like to do this on Linux where I have the desired apk files in a directory. I'd like to do this by hand if possible to that I can understand the ZIP's contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This simplified example is inspired by [this xda-developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=732957).

It is handy to use `adb` but you don't need to.

### Get a Java signing tool and keys

Your packaged ZIP needs to be signed. If you have a Java signing tool, great. If not, then you can consult the Google sources for [signapk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/7e447ed/tools/signapk) or download a ready-made `signapk.jar` from [here](https://github.com/appium/sign/raw/master/dist/signapk.jar), or [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/download/SignApk.zip).

The latter also contains sample signing keys that you can use but you can [make your own](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files) with OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
$ openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in request.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.pk8 -nocrypt
```

The following discussion assumes that you have a `signapk` directory containing `signapk.jar`, private key `key.pk8` and certificate  `certificate.pem`(which contains the corresponding public key).

#### Prepare the ZIP contents

Create a working directory (the name is irrelevant):

```
$ mkdir apkzip
$ cd apkzip
```

Create the required structure

```
$ mkdir -p META-INF/com/google/android system/app
```

The next step is to create a file called `updater-script` that contains a script written in something called [edify](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/inside_packages.html). A simple script that serves the requirement is shown below:

```
# META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
mount("MTD", "system", "/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system", "/system");
package_extract_dir("system", "/system");
unmount("/system");
```

The third parameter to `mount` is the block device path for the `system` partition. You can (optionally) verify this with:

```
$ adb shell grep system /proc/mounts
/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system /system ext4 ...
```

You can embellish the `updater-script` with comments and progress bars, as illistrated by may examples on the web but it isn't necessary.

You also need to provide the interpreter for the script which is a file called `update-binary` that you can obtain from whatever rom you're using, such as CyanogenMod or ResurrectionRemix. Find it in the ROM's Zip file at the location `META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary` and copy it into the working directory tree at a similar location and alongside the `updater-script` created in the previous step.

Finally copy in the `.apk` files that you want in your ZIP. They need to go in individual directories like `system/app/<app-name>/<apk-file>` where `<appName>` is a directory named after the app (I don't think the name is relevant) and `<apk-file>` is the `.apk` file. There should be one `.apk` file per directory.

Your file hierarchy should now look similar to this:

```
./META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
./META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary
./system/app/SomeApp/com.some.app.apk
./system/app/SomeOtherApp/com.some.other.app.apk
```

#### Create and sign the ZIP

Now create the signed ZIP (the `-r` recurses subdirectories):

```
$ zip -r /tmp/apps.zip *
$ cd ../signapk
$ java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 /tmp/apps.zip apps.zip
```

#### Apply the ZIP to your device

Push the signed ZIP (the `apps.zip` created in the current (`signapk`) directory) to the device, choose a location that your recovery can see:

```
$ adb push apps.zip /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1/
```

(You don't have to use `adb` - you can use another method such as placing the SD card in your computer, etc).

Now reboot to recovery and flash or, in the case of a locked bootloader, use FlashFire or whatever method is prefferred for your device.

#### Other notes

You can read more about Edify:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Edify_script_language
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=994940

It may be possible to replace `update-binary` with a shell script. An example of this can be seen in the [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/) ZIP files but I have not tried this.

The above works provided that the apps have no native libraries in them. If they do, then they must be be manually extracted from the `.apk` package (which is itself a ZIP file) `/lib` directory and placed under `/system/vendor/lib` in addition to placing the package in `/system/app/...`.

As commented by @DeathMaskSalesman, signing is not required by TWRP, CWM or FlashFire so you can skip the signing steps if you prefer.

I have produced a utility that works on Linux or Android. Get *apkzip* [here](https://github.com/johnlane/android_apkzip).

Comment: When flashing from **CWM** or **TWRP**, one can generally save themselves the hassle of signing the ZIP. You can also try my [Flashable ZIP Generator](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/143308/152843).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I had seen your script but I didn't understand it. Since understanding enough to be able to write this answer, I have taken another look at your script and I have some questions which I'll ask [there](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/143308/152843)...